# Adding wsse:security element to soap header

Tags: c#, wcf, api, soap, wcf-binding

I'm currently trying to connect to the hmrc's api and have set up a service in my project and am now in the process of creating the message to send.

I've been able to create the body section of the message fine, but am having trouble getting the header right. here's an example of what the message should look like:

```
<soap:Envelope  
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"  
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"  
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"  
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soap:Header>     
<wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/security/trust/RST/Issue</wsa:Action> 
<wsa:MessageID>uuid:39610e5b-162b-4491-9301-85578046a583</wsa:MessageID> 
<wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:Address>
        http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous
    </wsa:Address> 
</wsa:ReplyTo> 
<wsa:To>
    http://www.gateway.gov.uk/soap/2007/02/sts
</wsa:To> 
<wsse:Security> 
  <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-201ebb7a-d2f4-44d5-85e4-b8bb4c71ed54"> 
    <wsu:Created>2012-04-13T16:18:11Z</wsu:Created> 
    <wsu:Expires>2012-04-13T16:23:11Z</wsu:Expires> 
  </wsu:Timestamp> 
</wsse:Security> 
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body> 
<wst:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/trust"> 
<wst:TokenType>urn:GSO-SystemServices:external:1.65:gatewaytoken#GatewayToken</wst:TokenType>     
<wst:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/04/security/trust/Issue</wst:RequestType> 
  <wst:Base> 
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-94d12e0f-400b-4412-bde8-e03357eb0692"> 
      <wsse:Username>513FDQ37JILL</wsse:Username> 
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasisopen.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"> 
        NXJ3ynAa8Sy136aifThXJl8vLoE= 
      </wsse:Password> 
      <wsse:Nonce>4nJy2oD6xC79zatTHvuywg==</wsse:Nonce> 
      <wsu:Created>2007-02-01T11:03:10Z</wsu:Created> 
    </wsse:UsernameToken> 
  </wst:Base> 
  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/policy"> 
    <wsa:EndpointReference> 
      <wsa:Address>urn:GSO-SystemServices:external:1.65:GatewayWebServices</wsa:Address> 
    </wsa:EndpointReference> 
  </wsp:AppliesTo> Version 1.0 32 9 June 2008 
  <wst:Lifetime> 
    <wsu:Expires>2012-04-13T20:23:11Z</wsu:Expires> 
  </wst:Lifetime> 
</wst:RequestSecurityToken> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

The main issue is i can't get the Security element to show. I've currently been playing around in the app.config file trying out various types of binding, but i'm really new to using services and am getting completely stuck. Here's my current app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="XmlTokenServiceBinding" >
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" includeTimestamp="True" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
                        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
               </security>                
               <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <clientVia viaUri="https://secure.gateway.gov.uk/soap/2007/02/sts/GatewayTokenService.ashx"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://secure.gateway.gov.uk/soap/2007/02/sts/GatewayTokenService.ashx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="XmlTokenServiceBinding"
            contract="ServiceReference1.XmlTokenServicePortType" name="XmlTokenServicePort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

edit: Code as requested in comments for calling service:

```
  TokenService.RequestSecurityToken request = CreateTokenRequest();   
  TokenService.XmlTokenServicePortTypeClient client = new TokenService.XmlTokenServicePortTypeClient();
  TokenService.RequestSecurityTokenResponseType response = client.RequestSecurityTokenRequest(request);
```

Also here is the request message through fiddler:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:0f43afa7-c22c-400b-87b2-c9b76bd0abdd</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://secure.gateway.gov.uk/soap/2007/02/sts/GatewayTokenService.ashx</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <t:RequestSecurityToken Context="uuid-829d42ad-a560-44aa-9be8-95c212d82762-1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
        <t:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</t:TokenType>
        <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
        <t:KeySize>256</t:KeySize>
        <t:BinaryExchange ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/spnego" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">YIGeBgYrBgEFBQKggZMwgZCgGjAYBgorBgEEAYI3AgIeBgorBgEEAYI3AgIKonIEcE5FR09FWFRTAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAcAAAABOP7thI+QdbUguCiBDWyeqYiLGof7AdxPVl4cuUPGbTiMyHDzMox/EGGxas/mzB/AAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEVyfDIyRYtIv9kqa6BepAo=</t:BinaryExchange>
    </t:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to call the service. You shouldn't have to "create the body section" or "get the header right". WCF should be doing that for you.

Comment: Your question led me to believe you were trying to construct the XML by hand. Are you manipulating XML or not?

Comment: well the body section is expecting a userToken which i have to create and put into the body section. As for the header, the rest of it is being created for me, its just this one section isn't.

Comment: Again, the way you say that suggests that you are building the XML. Are you building XML, or are you letting serialization work for you?

Answer (score 0):

do you have any additional specification of the service security configuration? seems like it will require not just one message but multiple message exchange (ws-trust). Also the sample message uses ws-addressing version 2004/03 which is not directly supported by wcf. All this may or may not be an issue in your case (maybe you just work directly with the STS)

To answer your immediate question - your setting should emit some kine of security header. Why do you think it does not? The WCF logs will nto show the security (unless configured to log at transport level). Use fiddler to see what actually goes on the wire.

Comment: i have already been using fiddler to see the request and response, which is how i know that there is currently no security header being created.

Comment: Ok. Please publish a full working soap sample (not just the security part) and the full soap message you are sending (via Fiddler).

Comment: Ok i've added the full sample and message to my original post

Comment: I still don't understand one thing. You use secure session (ws-secureconversation). This requires several round trips to the server to create the token and then the real call uses the toekn. Typically users let WCF do this negotiation for them and only do the real call. You seem to want to do all the token stuff yourself. Am I right?

Comment: well i think half the problem is that the service doesn't create all the stuff that the message is expected to contain. So i feel that i have to fill in these missing gaps.

Comment: but you are writing the client, you must assume the service is working or contact the vendor. if the service is wcf you should get its config. if not you should get the ws-policy from the wsdl (if exists) and a full sample of a working requests (which may be composed of multiple messages in your case)